# Clojure returning a list

Tags: clojure

I know this example is trivial because I think there is a clojure library function that will do this, that is not the point.

I have the following code

```
(defn makelistres [a b res]
  (if (= a b) res (makelistres a (dec b) (conj res b))))

(defn makelist [a b]
  (makelistres a b [])
)
```

Is there a way to do the same effect without having to pass the list as a parameter? Such as throwing it on the stack

Such as

```
(defn test [a b]
  (if (= a b) 0 (+ 1 (test a (dec b))))
)
```

Don't know if the parenthesis match up, as I wrote this in this text box, but you get the point.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean, but you can certainly avoid having a res parameter by using a loop instead. if you are instead concerned about recursive calls consuming stack, recur can avoid this.

Comment: Yes the ultimate goal is to avoid the res parameter, is there a way to do so without loop?

Comment: What is it your `makelistres` function does? I'm sure it works, but I'd just like to know what to expect when running it at the REPL.

Comment: i guess it s like `(vec (range b a -1))` but with stack overflow if `a > b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is it an option to add one more arity to a function, which will then call the function with additional arg (empty vector) ?

like this:

```
(defn makelist
  ([a b] (makelist a b []))
  ([a b res]
    (if (== a b) res (makelist a (dec b) (conj res b)))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (makelist 1 10)
[10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2]
```

if not, the `loop` will do:

```
(defn makelist [a b]
  (loop [a a b b res []]
    (if (== a b)
      res
      (recur a (dec b) (conj res b)))))
```

or like this (since `a` is not changed):

```
(defn makelist [a b]
  (loop [b b res []]
    (if (== a b)
      res
      (recur (dec b) (conj res b)))))
```

but yeah, there is a lib function for that:
`(range 10 1 -1)`

Answer (score -2):

John

There are a couple of ways:

**`(def res [1,2,3,4,5])`**

However this requires a priori definition of the data before calling `makelistres`. There are ways to do this.

**`(def res-val (atom [])`**

This is more flexible using atom based functions to set and retrieve programmatically. However; you are using a mutable (stateful) object. Your ideology may shun this!

Because you are changing the content of `res` the `atom` approach seems more suited. You would basically set the value of the `res (using swap)` item from `makelist` and `derefing (e.g. @res)` it or modifying it in the recursion of `makelistres`.